# How to change root name  to our organization name in JasperReport Server 4.5?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am running *JasperReport Server 4.5* and now I want to change 'root' directory name to our Organization name in JR Server repository or it could be anything.

How can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JasperReports Server, I'm not sure that you can change the name of the root folder. In iReport, I am using the repository plug-in and I gave my server a name (right click > Server Settings). However, over in JasperReports Server it still shows "root".

If you want to change your top-level organization, however, from the top menu, choose "Manage", then "Organizations". Click on the organization that you want to edit, and click the "Edit" button. Then you can change the organization name and alias.